# $4\times 4$ Determinant solution verification

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, determinant

I am trying to compute the following determinant and attempting to figure out where I have gone wrong. If someone can point to it, that'd be great. Here is the matrix:

$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 4 & 8 & -1 \\ 5 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & 1 & 2 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & -1 & 2 \end{vmatrix}$

First, I expand these into four $3\times 3$ determinants as follows:

$=1\cdot\begin{vmatrix} 6 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & -1 \\ -1 & -1 & 2  \end{vmatrix} -4\cdot\begin{vmatrix} 5 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & 2 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & 2 \end{vmatrix} + 8\cdot \begin{vmatrix} 5 & 6 & 0 \\ 3 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & 2 \end{vmatrix}-(-1)\cdot \begin{vmatrix} 5 & 6 & 0 \\ 3 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & -1 & -1 \end{vmatrix}$

Then, we expand these determinants:

$=1 [6(4-1)]-4[(5)(4-1)] + 8[5(1)-6(6+1)] + 1[5(-1+2)-6(-5)]$

This gave me $-308$. WolframAlpha says it's $-303.$ Where have I made my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: If you instead expand along the second row, you only need to compute two $3\times3$ determinants.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you made a mistake in your final computation. Your sum is equal to -303, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%20%5B6%284-1%29%5D-4%5B%285%29%284-1%29%5D%20%2B%208%5B5%281%29-6%286%2B1%29%5D%20%2B%201%5B5%28-1%2B2%29-6%28-5%29%5D).

Answer (score 1):

The google calculator says

$$
1[6(4−1)]−4[(5)(4−1)]+8[5(1)−6(6+1)]+1[5(−1+2)−6(−5)] = -303
$$

so your error is arithmetic at the end.